# New Layout For New Page in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6, orchard-modules

is there a way to display a new page with a new layout?
Right now what I'm doing is to create a new module but without using [Themed] 
I'm looking for a simpler way to do it?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using an alternate for the layout shape? If you add a `layout-url-whatever.cshtml` to your theme's views, you should be able to override the layout just for that page. Details here: http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Alternates/

Answer (score 0):

Assumed by layout you mean theme you can implement `Orchard.Themes.IThemeSelector` to select a specific theme. Here is an example which shows a theme selector which picks the theme based on a `ThemePickerPart`:

```
public class ThemePickerPartThemeSelector : Orchard.Themes.IThemeSelector
{
  public ThemePickerPartThemeSelector(Orchard.ContentManagement.IContentManager aContentManager)
  {
    mContentManager = aContentManager;
  }

  public Orchard.Themes.ThemeSelectorResult GetTheme(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext aContext)
  {
    // get current content item, based on http://www.ideliverable.com/blog/getting-the-current-content-item-in-orchard
    object lID;

    if (aContext.RouteData.Values.TryGetValue("id", out lID))
    {
      string lIDStr = lID as string;

      if (lIDStr != null)
      {
        int lContentID;

        if(int.TryParse(lIDStr as string, out lContentID))
        {
          // try to get theme from theme picker part
          var lContentItem = mContentManager.Get(lContentID, Orchard.ContentManagement.VersionOptions.Published);

          if (lContentItem != null)
          {
            var lThemePickerPart = lContentItem.As<ThemePickerPart>();

            if (lThemePickerPart != null)
            {
              if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lThemePickerPart.ThemeId))
              {
                // return selected theme
                var lResult = new Orchard.Themes.ThemeSelectorResult {Priority = -3, ThemeName = lThemePickerPart.ThemeId};

                return lResult;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return null; // use configured theme
  }

  // private
    private Orchard.ContentManagement.IContentManager mContentManager;
}
```

Comment: it's not actually a theme created using codegen but just a simple page I get from elsewhere, I want to display it using orchard page. The page already has its own jquery, etc